# K8S pods with two replicas on different nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

I've pods with two replicas, does it make sense that k8s will reschedule  **both replicas in the same time**?
if yes is there a way to avoid it ?

I guess(according to the replies from @Henry) that I need to use https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity or

topology
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/

But not sure how to configure following:

`1` application with `2` replicas that for example

`Replica A` runs on `nodeFoo` and

`Replica B` run in `NodeBar`

Comment: Normally, they would not be rescheduled unless something bad happens (OOM, node died, ...). Find out, why they were rescheduled.

Comment: @Henry - thanks, we are checking it right now. is there a way to tell to application to run with two replicas on two different nodes ? to minimize the risk of both reschedule on the same time ?

Comment: "run with two replicas on two different nodes": have a look at affinity: podAntiAffinity: in the POD template specification.

Comment: @Henry - thanks I read it, but what am I missing here that how would you do it for `specific  app` to tell it two different node ,could you please provide example as answer?

Comment: I believe that [daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) could be a better choice in this case, if you want 1 replica running in each node. What do you think?

Comment: @KoopaKiller - thanks,1. what is the benfit of using deamonset over affinty? 2. in case I have 10 nodes and I want that the demonset will run only on 2 nodes, is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To configure the replicas  to run on different nodes `podAntiAffinity` can be used. For example in the deployment spec:

```
spec:    
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: my-app-label
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  name: my-app-label
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

This basically means, all pods matched by the label `name=my-app-label` should run on hosts where the node label `kubernetes.io/hostname` is different.

Comment: THanks, not sure I understand it, how here you tell run on two diffrent node, you put only ` podAntiAffinity:` but you didint tell it to run on `node X` and `node Y`, could you please explain?you dont need to define `topologySpreadConstraints` ?

Comment: thanks, just to verify that I fully understnad. in case have `10 nodes` and I use the `podAntiAffinity:` with the `topologyKey`  and one app with 5 replica, `each` instance of the 5 pods will be scheduled in `different` node as each node have diffrent `kubernetes.io/hostname` , am I right?

Comment: @JennyM yes that's rights. No two pods will run on the same node.

Comment: @Henry what about deploying 2nd replica on `other nodes group (any node out of 2)` while the 1st replica on `main node group (any node out of 3)` ?? I mean is it possible to do so usin podAntiAffinity ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a Deployment, yes the Pod objects are created and scheduled roughly simultaneously. If you want things to be created in order, use a StatefulSet.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I need to use ` affinity: podAntiAffinity` but not sure how to do for a one app to specify two diffrent node, each app replica will go to diffrent node...

Comment: There are many ways to control how pods are distributed. An antiaffinity is one of, pod topology spread is another. It depends on your needs and Kubernetes version.

Comment: It will be great if you can provide example for pod topology/affinity that 1 pod with two replica in two different nodes...